# Static Factory Instantiation of bean vs factory Instantiation of bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In Spring we can do Instantiation of bean by using factory and static factory. 
In what all scenarios we should go for factory and static factory ? 
Which one is better option instatiate the bean in Spring and its pros and cons?

Using Static Factory

```
<bean id="clientService"  class="examples.ClientService" 
 factory-method="createInstance"/>

public class ClientService {
private static ClientService clientService = new ClientService();
private ClientService() {}

public static ClientService createInstance() {
    return clientService;
}
```

}

Using Factory

```
<bean id="serviceLocator" class="examples.DefaultServiceLocator">
<!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
```

```
<bean id="clientService"
factory-bean="serviceLocator"
factory-method="createClientServiceInstance"/>

<bean id="accountService"
factory-bean="serviceLocator"
factory-method="createAccountServiceInstance"/>

public class DefaultServiceLocator {

private static ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
private static AccountService accountService = new AccountServiceImpl();

private DefaultServiceLocator() {}

public ClientService createClientServiceInstance() {
    return clientService;
}

public AccountService createAccountServiceInstance() {
    return accountService;
}
```

}

Comment: @kedarkamathe Please post some example code before other users (excluding me) close the question as too broad.

Comment: Second example does not look like factory for me

Comment: its the example from Spring documentation.

Comment: static factory allows you to create class, in bean factory, you could instantiate interface